# how to test asynchronous methods Swift

Tags: swift

I have following class that I want to run from unites:

```
class WmBuildGroupsTask{

init(){}

    func doInBackground() -> WmTransferItem{
         NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(20)// sleep 20 sec to simulate long task
                            }

    func onPostExecute(transferItem:WmTransferItem){        
        //called when long task finished        
    }


    func execute(){        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

            var  transItem:WmTransferItem = self.doInBackground()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.onPostExecute(transItem)
                });
            });                
      }    
}
```

I tried to run from Unitest file:

```
var task:WmBuildGroupsTask = WmBuildGroupsTask()
task.execute();
```

but test is done before `doInBackground()` method finished.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `XCTestExpectation`<sup>(since Xcode 6)</sup>.

How it works:

We create `XCTestExpectation` instance that work like timer. Your test will never finish till one of both cases happend:

- `XCTestExpectation.fulfill()` called
- you got timeout defined with `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` and therefore test will fail

### How to use `XCTestExpectation`

**Step 1**

Create new protocol for class under test (in your case `WmBuildGroupsTask`):

```
protocol MyCallback{
    func onDone(results: String)
}
```

This is our *callback*.

**Step 2**

in Unitest inherit this protocol:

```
class Test_WmBuildGroupsTask : XCTestCase, MyCallback {
/* ...*/    
}
```

**Step 3**

create `XCTestExpectation` variable (in `Test_WmBuildGroupsTask`):

```
var theExpectation:XCTestExpectation?
```

and initiate `onDone()` method:

```
func onDone(results: String){
    
    theExpectation?.fulfill() // it will release our "timer"
}
```

**Step 4**

Example of our test:

```
func test___WmBuildGroupsTask() {
   
    // Declare  expectation
     theExpectation = expectationWithDescription("initialized") // dummy text
   
    var task:WmBuildGroupsTask = WmBuildGroupsTask()
    task.delegate = self // pass delegate to WmBuildGroupsTask class        
    task.execute();

    
    // Loop until the expectation is fulfilled in onDone method
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(500, { error in XCTAssertNil(error, "Oh, we got timeout")
    })
}// end func
```

---

So now what left us to do is to add some stuff to `WmBuildGroupsTask`:

**Step 5**

add new variable:

```
var delegate:MyCallback?
```

change `onPostExecute` method to:

```
func onPostExecute(transferItem:WmTransferItem){
   /* .. */

   delegate?.onDone("finished")// call callback        
}
```

---

Thats all.

*<sub>( Tested )</sub>*

Comment: I hope there was a easier way to do this.. All this code to just get a Test to wait sucks..

Comment: @Siddharth you welcome to share with your thoughts. Hope today the process should be easier.