# Asynchronous Swift Testing of Protocols with XCTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to write a REST Api class in swift and test it.  I was attempting to follow the methodology in: [how to test asynchronous methods Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342398/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods-swift) but I seem to have run into an issue.

### Client/RestInterface.swift

```
import Foundation


protocol RestSearchProtocol {
    func didRecieveResponse(results: NSDictionary)
}


public class RestInterface : NSObject {
    // lots of code we don't care about ...
}
```

### ClientTests/RestInterfaceTests.swift

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import Client

class RestInterfaceTests: XCTestCase, RestSearchProtocol {
// ... rest of the test file
```

I'm getting an undeclared type error.

[image]

Any suggestions as how to make this work?

*As a side note - if i take the **RestInterfaceTests** class and put it at the end of **RestInterface.swift** it seems to find the protocol, but **XCTestCase** is now undeclared*

Answer (score 0):

It appears i was missing the **public** identifier:

```
import Foundation


public protocol RestSearchProtocol {
    func didRecieveResponse(results: NSDictionary)
}


public class RestInterface : NSObject {
    // lots of code we don't care about ...
}
```

has solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

use 
`@testable import Client`
You don't need to set your types as public anymore!